# Android : Back button is acting odd

Tags: android

I have a strange problem and really dont know where to start debug. I have 2 activities one that holds a googlemap view and when the user taps the marker on the view i start a new activity that shows a detailed description of that marker. If i hit the back buttton on my detalied activity it returns me to the map activity, so far so good. BUT if i tap a new (or same) marker i get to the detailed activity again (all fine) if i try to hit the back button again i get returned to the detailed activity that i tapped the very first time, and i can hit back once more and finaly get to the map activity again.

if i keep debugggin i can get up to 10 activities that i have to push back on before i finaly get to the map activity again

what the heck is going on ? does android forget history or something due to i implement the map activity instead of activity ?

anyone that has an idea of where to start looking for the problem

Here comes a lot of code:

map activity

```
public class SpotGuideMapActivity extends MapActivity
{
    protected MapView mapView;
    protected MapController mapController;
    protected List<Overlay> mapOverlays;
    protected Drawable overlayIcon;
    protected SpotGuideOverlay spotsOverlay;
    protected MyLocationOverlay myLocOverlay;

    protected ArrayList<SpotItem> _spots;

    protected Button ButtonHome;
    protected Button ButtonPreferences;

    protected Intent _intent = null;


    private SpotGuideDbAdapter _spotDbAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.spot_map);
        _intent = getIntent();
        ActivityHelper.createInstance(this).setTopBarTitle("Spot kortet");

        ButtonPreferences = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPreferences);
        ButtonPreferences.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {


                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GlobalPreferencesActivity.class));         
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_right_in,R.anim.slide_right_out);
            }
        });

        ButtonHome = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnHome);
        ButtonHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class));         
                 overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_left_in,R.anim.slide_left_out);
            }
        });


        //mapView.invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() 
    {
        super.onResume();
        if(_intent.hasExtra("latitude") && _intent.hasExtra("longitude"))
        {
            String latitude = _intent.getStringExtra("latitude");
            String longitude = _intent.getStringExtra("longitude");
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
            double lon = Double.parseDouble(longitude);

            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(lat * 1E6) , (int)(lon * 1E6));
            initMapView(point);
        }
        else
        {
            initMapView(null);
        }

        drawSpotMarkers();

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() 
    {
        super.onPause();
        myLocOverlay.disableCompass();
        myLocOverlay.disableMyLocation();

    }

    protected void initMapView(GeoPoint centerPoint) 
    {

        mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.spotGuideMap);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapController = mapView.getController();

        //current location overlayer
        myLocOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
        myLocOverlay.enableCompass();
        myLocOverlay.enableMyLocation();

        mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocOverlay);

        GeoPoint point = null;
        if(centerPoint == null)
        {
            point = myLocOverlay.getMyLocation();
            if(point == null)   
            {
                point = new GeoPoint((int)(55.5616508394963 * 1E6) , (int)(12.563638687133789 * 1E6));
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            point = centerPoint;
        }
        //get the last know location, be fresh so use last fix
        //Location location = myLocOverlay.getLastFix();
        //GeoPoint locationPoint;

        //locationPoint = new GeoPoint((int)(location.getLatitude() * 1E6) , (int)(location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

        mapController.animateTo(point);
        mapController.setZoom(10);      
    }

    protected void drawSpotMarkers() 
    {
        mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();

        overlayIcon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.map_icon_pink);
        spotsOverlay = new SpotGuideOverlay(overlayIcon, this);

        _spotDbAdapter = new SpotGuideDbAdapter(this).Open();
        _spots = _spotDbAdapter.getAllSpots();

        for (SpotItem spot : _spots) 
        {
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(spot.getLatitude());
            double lon = Double.parseDouble(spot.getLongitude());

            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(lat * 1E6) , (int)(lon * 1E6));

            OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, spot.getSpotTitle(), Integer.toString(spot.getId()));

            spotsOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
        }


        mapOverlays.add(spotsOverlay);


    }


    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() 
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

detailed activity

```
public class SpotGuideDescriptionActivity extends BaseActivity
{
    private SpotGuideDbAdapter _spotDbAdapter;

    protected Button ButtonHome;
    protected Button ButtonPreferences;

    protected Button ButtonBacktoMap;

    protected TextView tvSpotTitle;
    protected TextView tvSpotType;
    protected TextView tvWindDirection;
    protected TextView tvContent;

    protected Intent _intent = null;
    protected SpotItem item;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.spot_description);
        _intent = getIntent();

        this.getActivityHelper().setTopBarTitle("Spot beskrivelse");

        tvSpotTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.spotDescTitle);
        tvSpotType = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.spotDescType);
        tvWindDirection = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.spotDescWind);
        tvContent = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.spotDescContent);

        ButtonBacktoMap = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBackToMap);
        ButtonBacktoMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SpotGuideMapActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("latitude", item.getLatitude());
                intent.putExtra("longitude", item.getLongitude());
                startActivity(intent);                    
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_left_in,R.anim.slide_left_out);
            }
        });

        ButtonPreferences = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPreferences);
        ButtonPreferences.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {


                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GlobalPreferencesActivity.class));         
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_right_in,R.anim.slide_right_out);
            }
        });

        ButtonHome = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnHome);
        ButtonHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class));         
                 overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_left_in,R.anim.slide_left_out);
            }
        });

        init();
    }

    private void init()
    {
        if(_intent.hasExtra("spot_id"))
        {
            int id = _intent.getIntExtra("spot_id", 0);
            _spotDbAdapter = new SpotGuideDbAdapter(this).Open();

            item = _spotDbAdapter.getSpot(id);
            tvSpotTitle.setText(item.getSpotTitle());
            tvSpotType.setText(item.getSpotType());
            tvWindDirection.setText(item.getWindDirections());
            tvContent.setText(item.getSpotDescription());
        }
    }
}
```

And i init the tap in my OverlayItem like this

```
public boolean onTap(int index)
    {
        OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);

        Intent descIntent = new Intent(currentContext.getApplicationContext(), SpotGuideDescriptionActivity.class);
        descIntent.putExtra("spot_id", item.getSnippet());
        currentContext.startActivity(descIntent);

        return false;

    }
```

it is not the BackToMap button that i use, it is the back button on all phones

Comment: where you are starting `SpotGuideDescriptionActivity`?

Comment: thx for point it out :) i do it ontap in my spotguideoverlay that extends com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't worked with maps, so I may be off my rocker.  But the fact that you are calling         initMapView() in OnResume() might be creating two markers one on top of the other (and again, every time you go back).  So when you think you are taping on one marker, you are actually taping on multiple markers.

That's just off the top of my head, and can be total malarkey.

Comment: ust off the top of your head ? well done mate and thx mate. worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution would be to @Override `onBackPressed()` to open the map activity back up. This might lead to you having to do it to navigate the entire app, though. If it's just that map page and the overlay with more info, you can easily just have this on the page that is duplicating:

```
@Override
onBackPressed(){ 
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

then on the activity with the mapview

```
@Override
onBackPressed(){ 
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```